# MongoDB .NET Driver update Cannot use the part ... to traverse the element

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-update

I'm trying to rename a field but I end up getting an error. What could I be missing?

> A write operation resulted in an error.
> cannot use the part (Orders of Orders.Number) to traverse the element ({Orders: [ { CustomFields: { Пара паков: { FieldId: ObjectId('61e670f9c0fe1106a51a2e23'), Type: "Text", ValueBson: "8989" }, Weight: { FieldId: ObjectId('6149d5de44175b8324482915'), Type: "Number", ValueBson: 2222 } }, _id: ObjectId('61e6751027c21629e070091b'), Number: "21312" } ]})

```cs
var orderFilter = Builders<VisitTask>.Filter.Empty;
UpdateDefinition<VisitTask> update = Builders<VisitTask>.Update.Rename($"Orders.Number", $"Orders.TestNumber");
Collection.UpdateMany(orderFilter, update, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61e674fa27c21629e070091a"),
    "LastUpdateDate" : ISODate("2022-01-18T08:07:52.008Z"),
    "Orders" : [ 
        {
            "CustomFields" : {
                "Пара паков" : {
                    "FieldId" : ObjectId("61e670f9c0fe1106a51a2e23"),
                    "Type" : "Text",
                    "ValueBson" : "8989"
                }
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("61e6751027c21629e070091b"),
            "Number" : "21312"
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rename` operator is not able to work in updating the field name in a nested array.

Instead, you need `$set` the existing `Number` value(s) to new field `TestNumber` with **`$map`**. Then `$unset` to remove `Orders.TestNumber` field.

Note: The previous answer will result in incorrect output. Need to use **`$map`** for updating the objects in array.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      Orders: {
        $map: {
          input: "$Orders",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                "Number-test": "$$this.Number"
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "Orders.Number"
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-P3QzJ85PH5)

---

**[For MongoDB .Net Driver version 2.13]**

To C#, you need to use [`UpdateDefinitionBuilder<TDocument>.Pipeline` Method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateDefinitionBuilder_1_Pipeline.htm) as below:

**Solution 1**

```cs
UpdateDefinition<VisitTask> update = Builders<VisitTask>.Update.Pipeline(
    new PipelineStagePipelineDefinition<VisitTask, VisitTask>(
        new PipelineStageDefinition<VisitTask, VisitTask>[]
        {
            new BsonDocument("$set", 
                new BsonDocument("Orders", 
                    new BsonDocument("$map", 
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "input", "$Orders" }, 
                            { "in", 
                                new BsonDocument("$mergeObjects", 
                                    new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        new BsonDocument("Number-test", "$$this.Number"),
                                        "$$this"
                                    }) 
                            }
                        }))),
            new BsonDocument("$unset", "Orders.Number")
        }));
```

**Solution 2**

```cs
UpdateDefinition<VisitTask> update = Builders<VisitTask>.Update.Pipeline(
    new BsonDocument[]
    {
        new BsonDocument("$set", 
            new BsonDocument("Orders", 
                new BsonDocument("$map", 
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "input", "$Orders" }, 
                        { "in", 
                            new BsonDocument("$mergeObjects", 
                                new BsonArray
                                {
                                    new BsonDocument("Number-test", "$$this.Number"),
                                    "$$this"
                                }) 
                        }
                    }))),
        new BsonDocument("$unset", "Orders.Number")
    }
);
```

Comment: and in version 2.8.0 what will it look like?

Comment: After some attempts in the 2.8 version, I doubt this set & unset (rename) nested field in the array is not workable. Maybe you should look for the latest version MongoDB .Net Driver.

Comment: Ok, i tried to use your method also for the field "Пара паков",

Comment: "Orders" : [ 
        {
            "CustomFields" : {
                "Пара паков-test" : [ 
                    []
                ]
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("61e6751027c21629e070091b"),
            "TestNumber" : [ 
                "21312"
            ]
        }
    ],

Comment: as a result, the array broke

Comment: i did like this

Comment: original `Пара паков` value is object or array? Can you show how you update this field?

Comment: new BsonDocument("$set",
                new BsonDocument("Orders.CustomFields.Пара паков-тест", "$Orders.CustomFields.Пара паков")),
            new BsonDocument("$unset", "Orders.CustomFields.Пара паков")

Comment: this object I described above how to update it

Comment: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HXMUsQnSs2d). I verified in both MongoPlayground & C# it works correctly.

Comment: It's weird, I'm creating a new array with this element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241174/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-jonnyjon44).

Comment: I also duplicated the code in the chat and above in the post